# Will there be performance problems by connecting a PCI-E 3.0 X16 GPU in a PCI-E 2.0 X16 slot

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, nvidia-graphics-card

Hi im thinking of upgradering my ffmpeg server, i currently have 2 nvidia P4000 gpu and want to buy some more, but the thing is that, my Motherboard only have 2 PCI-E 3.0 X16 slots, so i googled and found some mining Motherboards that have 1 PCI-E 3.0 X16 and minimum 8 PCI-E 2.0 x1, so my plan was to buy some PCI-E 2.0 x1 to PCI-E 2.0 x16 rising. so my question is, will there be any performance problems by putting PCI-E 3.0 x16 into PCI-E 2.0 x16 slots

Comment: Your bigger concern should be going from x1 motherboard slot to x16 riser. That is a loss of 16 fold in bandwidth.  I don't know how much bandwidth ffmpeg uses vs processing power so you could be alright.  Mining is 99% gpu processor dependent and uses very little bandwidth so they function just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCI is backwards compatible, so there is no restriction, any card will work in any
PCI Express slot.

It is claimed that every generation of PCIE doubles the bandwidth of the last one,
but testing has not shown much difference for
PCI-E 3.0 x16 running on PCI-E 2.0.

Some references:

- [Toms Hardware : PCI Express 3.0 x16 graphic card on PCI Express 2.0 x16 slot?](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2141520/pci-express-x16-graphic-card-pci-express-x16-slot.html)
- [Does the PCIE 2.0 X16 graphics card work in a PCIE 3.0 x16 slot?](https://www.quora.com/Does-the-PCIE-2-0-X16-graphics-card-work-in-a-PCIE-3-0-x16-slot)